# Error in update

Tags: update-manager

/etc/resolv.conf?

```
Err:4 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release                       
  403  Forbidden
Err:5 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release               
  403  Forbidden
Err:6 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release             
  403  Forbidden
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
E: The repository 'http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you do when this happened?

Comment: i just want to update so i used sudo apt update command and it shows this result and i reboot my system but it shows again same message

Comment: It is possibly a temporary problem, but if you can't wait you could remove the `np.` country code in front of `archive.ubuntu.com` ; ie. point it to the main site; the default site had no issues (get:7)